# Insert lots of data at once using Laravel migrations?

Tags: laravel, migration

I currently parse a CSV file to insert data into a database, but the problem is that because it's 20 000 rows, it takes very long. Is there a way to insert more lines at once using Laravel migrations?

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
foreach ($towns as $town) {
   DB::table('town')->insert(
      array(
         // data goes here
      )
   );
}
```

I think maybe my question is a bit vague. I want to know what the format is to mass insert multiple items using one query, and if this will actually make a difference in speed?

Comment: I have had problem with this aswell, but if you split the $towns array/object up into smaller pieces, i think it will work. make it maximum of 5000 entries per array

Comment: also check this package out https://github.com/Maatwebsite/laravel4-PHPExcel

Comment: The PHPExcel package can be very useful when you need to preserve spreadsheet formatting data, or create spreadsheets, but I'd avoid using it here as it's extremely memory hungry and would simply make the OP's problem worse.

Comment: When inserting, instead of passing in an array of data for each table row, you can pass in an unindexed array of arrays, which is marginally faster than passing in rows one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mass insert by filling an array with your data:

```
foreach ($towns as $town) {
   $array[] = array(... your data goes here...);
}
```

And then run it just once

```
DB::table('town')->insert($array);
```

But I really don't know how much faster it can be. You can also disable query log:

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
```

It uses less memory and is usually faster.